# Where had you been ready to go?

Tags: grammaticality, past-perfect

Does this sentence make sense in English?

> Where had you been ready to go?

Second question:

If that sentence doesn't make sense, why would the question of this sentence be using "ready"?

> I was ready to go (Where).

Comment: You might need to say "Where had you been ready to go **to**" (or "To where had you been ready to go") to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I would probably say "Where were you going?", assuming that the previous discussion had established that "you" had been preparing to go somewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct way of phrasing this question would be "Where had you been ready to go to?" or "Where were you ready to go to?"

Rather than ending with "ready to go" you should end the sentence with "ready to go **to**"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a grammatical reason why  "Where had you been ready to go?" is incorrect? Is "Where did you go?" incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

**"Where had you been ready to go?" is correct.**

---

> "Where had you been ready to go?"

**This is known as [*past perfect continuous*](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfectcontinuous.html):** we use the Past Perfect Continuous to show that something started in the past and continued up until another time in the past.

---

> "Where were you ready to go?"

**This is a [*past continuous tense*](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html):** use this to indicate that a longer action in the past was interrupted. The interruption is usually a shorter action in the Simple Past. Remember this can be a real interruption or just an interruption in time.

---

Also, as @HotLicks stated, I would assume an established understanding of having been prepared, and leave off the "ready" portion.

> "Where were you going?"

This is also a ***past continuous tense***.

Comment: Thanks for answering. And what about "where were you ready to go __to__" as @Robusto and JaredKauffman said?

Comment: @Bora, I don't like the sound of that one bit.